# [ConcurrentHashMap]: Map update/get operation returns stale value from the map in single thread operation

Tags: java, caching, concurrenthashmap

For some `key` the map still holds stale value. A new update is not getting reflected for a few keys. This bug is in the `not reproducible` category.

Code:

```
 class DemoCache{

    private ConcurrentHashMap<String,Demo> demoByName = new ConcurrentHashMap<String,Demo>();
    private ConcurrentHashMap<String,Demo> demoByID = new ConcurrentHashMap<String,Demo>();

    public initializeFromDB(){

        log.info(me + "Initializing/refresh  instrument from database.");
        DemoDbDynamo demoDbDynamo = new DemoDbDynamo();

        final AtomicInteger progressCounter = new AtomicInteger();
        try
        {       
            demoDbDynamo.listAll()
                .stream()
                .peek(i -> progressCounter.incrementAndGet())
                .forEach(this::updateCache);            
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            log.error(me + "Exception fetching demo cache  from table. " + e );
        }
        log.info(me + "count: " + progressCounter.get());

      }

    }

    public void updateCache(Demo demo){

        Demo existing = demoByID.get(demo.getID());

        demoByID.put( dmeo.getID(), demo );
        // this is an updated existing demo
        if(existing != null) {
            //if name have changed
            demoByName.remove(existing.getName());
        }

        demoByName.put      ( demo.getName(),       demo );
        //logging new value -- demo.getName and demo.getValue
        //logging old value - demo.getName and demo.getValue

    }
}
```

Map size: 6k

The whole operation is single-threaded. JMS topic hit this class to initialize the map from DB.
We have 4 different servers and each server has this local cache which got refresh by JMS Topic msg. Out of 4, 3 server gets updated with all correct values and 1 server still holds the stale values for few keys.

What could be the root cause of this issue?

result updates from the comment:

Logs:

```
JMS msg

ip-10-0-33-185 20:15:40.374 [ThreadName=ActiveMQ Session Task-72] DEBUG cache.DemoCache {} -- DemoCache.onMessage() : [msg=<response mt='5099'/>]

ip-10-0-33-185 20:15:40.375 [ThreadName=ActiveMQ Session Task-72] INFO  cache.DemoCache {} -- DemoCache.initializeFromDB(): Initializing/refresh  cache from database.

ip-10-0-33-185 20:15:45.897 [ThreadName=ActiveMQ Session Task-72] DEBUG cache.DemoCache {} -- 
[newObject=[NewID=06926627-e950-48f3-9c53-b679f61120ec newName=foo,newValue=2640.98]]
[OldObject=[oldName=foo,oldValue=2641.05]]

ip-10-0-33-185 20:15:45.913 [ActiveMQ Session Task-72] INFO  cache.DemoCache {} -- DemoCache.initializeFromDB(): count: 5362
```

Here _collector = `ip-10-0-33-185` that is server node.
This server returns old value = 2641.05 instead of a new value.
Only one thread is running `ActiveMQ Session Task-72`. I don't see any other thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Despite using of ConcurrentHashMap the code is **not thread safe**.

Here is one possible scenario how inconsistency can occur. Suppose cache contains value `demo0` with an ID = "X". Suppose there are 2 threads, A and B. Thread A has the next version of the ibject with the same ID, say `demo1`. Thread B knows this `demo1` and in the meanwhile obtained the newer version of it, `demo2`.

Now both threads want to update the cache.

Thread A calls `updateCache()` with value `demo1`. After it called `Demo existing = ...` and before it called `demoByID.put(...)` this thread is suspended and thread B is executed. Thread B calls `updateCache()` with value `demo2`, is not interrupted and successfully puts value `demo2` to the cache.

Now thread A is continued. It executes `demoByID.put(...)` etc. But it works with `demo1`. So it puts `demo1` to the cache thus replacing the newer version `demo2` in `demoByID` and in `demoByName`.

What you can do?

All operations between checking existence and modifying the cache should be done as a block withing a single thread. For instance, use [**lock**](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/locks/Lock.html) for the whole contents of the method `updateCache()` or use declare method `updateCache()` **synchronized**.

Comment: I can use lock for `updateCache` method but this cron job always runs one time in the day and its single-threaded process. Even if I would use `lock` for the `UpdateCache` method will it make any difference as there only one thread. So the scenario that you explained would never occur in my case.

Comment: But even if the cron job is called only once, the application may have many threads. 1) How many threads do you use? 2) How do you process messages - synchronously or not? If asynchronously (e.g. there is more than 1 thread that processes messages), then what I described can happen.

Comment: @NDesai:  I'd suggest you add logging in the method "updateCache()" and write to the log current thread ID and the parameter passed to this method. Also, since logs are usually asynchronous, I'd suggest you increment an atomic counted in this method and write it to the log, too. Important: The counter should be a *static* variable, not a member variable like in your current code.

Comment: @NDesai: And it we see that all messages are processed synchronously, then there are further options: 3) It can be that the topic delivery policy is configured in such way, that it does not guarantee that delivery order is the same as send order. If the policy ensures the same order, this would mean that 4) messages are put to the topic not in then order you expect: sometimes messages with older object value are sent *after* messages with a newer object values. Let me know the results of checking of these 4 options.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I really appreciate your response. I have added those logs which you've asked and added the result which I have got. I am just sending a msg to refresh the cache and all the values are coming from DB. `mt='5099'` calls the DemoCache. initializeFromDB

Comment: @NDesai: We need a log that shows when *both* values were added. The log in your question is unfortunately too short. We don't see when "2641.05" was added. May be it was added 10ms before "2640.98". Then this *may* mean it was added by another thread just a moment before and we do need synchronization. If "2641.05" was added long time ago like 1 hour before "2640.98", this means the **sender** sent message in the such order. So you should **ask the sender** why these messages were sent in this order: first "2641.05", then "2640.98". If you get further details, post them here.

Comment: oldValue = "2641.05" was already added 12 hours ago and I am updating value to new value = "2640.98" after 12 hour. Values get updated every 12 hours.

Comment: @NDesai: Was the old value not replaced with a new one in this case? Is the oldValue = "2641.05" remained after new  "2640.98" was received?

Comment: @NDesai: You fill cache from DemoDbDynamo, but never save new values back. Ist it correct? Have you checked in what order is called initializeFromDB() and updateCache()? If updateCache() is called earlier, then of course new values will be overridden later on by the values from database. Make sure that updateCache() canbe called only after initializeFromDB() is completed.